# Microsoft Visual Studio MVC .Net Azure Reference Manifest Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2017, publish

I'm new to Azure deployment and am having major reference issues.

I'm developing a MVC project in Visual Studio 2017 and trying to use the Publish to Web function to deploy to Azure.

I have the following issue, when I use the local debugger, I can run the website perfectly.

When I do a Publish to Web (azure app service), I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject.Web.Common, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

The weird thing is I don't have Ninject.Web.Common installed at all and have done a search throughout the solution and haven't found a reference to Ninject at all. When I use the Nuget Package Manager to install 3.3.0.0, it'll start asking for version 3.2.0.0 instead.

If I put a dependentAssembly binding redirect so that 3.2.0.0 goes to 3.3.0.0, it'll throw another error about not finding a function.

Where is this manifest reference located and how can I change it? I can't find it in the web.config or the packages.config, so I'm unclear if there's something on Azure instead that's trying to reference these assemblies instead.

Comment: the key phrase is "or one of its dependencies" -- check the .NET framework version of your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm dumb.

I was publishing to another application's app service (long story, same app, but different framework and technology) and that was causing the issue.

Once I created an app service specifically for this application in Visual Studio, it works perfectly.